# why if(Request.IsAjaxRequest) is false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I wanted to have a hyperlink which when clicked opens in same page without the complete page being refreshed instead of opening different link.
In my controller I have following function

```
public ActionResult PrivacyPolicy()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
       return PartialView();
    }
       return View();
}
```

when i run the the program and insert a break point at `return view();` I realise that my program always returns `view()` instead of `PartialView();`

here is the `index.cshtml` code

```
@section head{

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/AjaxDemo.js")"></script>
}
@Html.ActionLink("Show the Privacy Policy", "PrivacyPolicy", null, new{id="privacyLink"})

<div id="privacy"></div>
```

in the partial view PrivacyPolicy I just have few texts.

and the `AjaxDemo.js` looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#privacyLink').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#privacy').load(url);
    });
});
```

why doesn't my program return partial view? or why is it not taking the ajax request?
Shouldn't my program open the link in same index page(CustomAjax), if the javascript in my browser is enables?

Comment: See these posts : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164540/why-doesnt-request-isajaxrequest-work-in-asp-net-mvc-3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607164/request-isajaxrequest-never-returns-true-in-mvc3

Comment: They don't really solve the my problem. But anyways thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC `event` is a reserved word. Try like this:

```
$('#privacyLink').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#privacy').load(url);
});
```

or:

```
$('#privacyLink').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#privacy').load(url);
    return false;
});
```

Also don't forget to include jQuery.js **before** your `AjaxDemo.js` script.

Comment: I tried the first option that you mentioned. and included `@section head {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Ajaxdemo.js")"></script>
    
}` but still on hyperlink click i get forwarded to new page

Comment: Make sure that jQuery is not included twice and that you don't have some javascript errors. Look at your javascript console in the browser as well as the Network tab to ensure that all your scripts are included properly. This should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, well I now got some kind of error on my AjaxDemo.js which is shown by javascript console. It says Uncaught reference error: $ is not defined just below the line `$('#privacyLink').click(function (e) {`. Any idea why am I getting that error?

Comment: Yes, you haven't referenced jquery or referenced it twice or simply `~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js` doesn't exist. From what I can see you have included this in a section called `head` but make sure that this section is properly included in your Layout and that you don't have a duplicate @Scripts.Render call for jQuery at the end of your DOM. By the way it's better to include all scripts at the end of the DOM and in this case you don't need to wrap your code in a `$(document).ready` callbacks.

Comment: Thank you very very much. Finally works now. I've spent my whole day trying to solve this thing.

Answer (score 2):

if you do a jQuery load, it will actually execute a normal request and then load the resulting data inside the given element.

You should remove the custom JavaScript code, use the built-in ajax helpers and specify the updateTargetID in the AjaxOptions:

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Show the Privacy Policy", "PrivacyPolicy", null, new{id="privacyLink"}, new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "privacy"})

    <div id="privacy"></div>
```

**EDIT**: Adding some more information about IsAjaxRequest():

When you make an Ajax request you're supposed to set the `X-Requested-With` HTTP header to `XMLHttpRequest'. Internally,`IsAjaxRequest` checks for the presence of this header.

When you use `jQuery.Ajax` or the default Ajax-helpers for that matter, this header will be included.
If you use `jQuery.load()` this header is not included. jQuery.load does not allow for custom headers to be set.

**Edit**
In order to use Ajax.ActionLink you need to include the unobtrusive ajax library and enable it in the web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

In addition to setting the flag, you will also need to include the MVC plugin for unobtrusive Ajax with jQuery (`~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`).

Comment: I replaced my `@Html.ActionLink`with the `@Ajax.ActionLink` like you mentioned. Now it takes me to this link http://localhost:19208/customajax/PrivacyPolicy/privacyLink when i click the SHow the privacy policy hyperlink. What should I do to make sure that when the hyperlink is clicked it is taken as Ajax request and open the partial view rather than the whole view. For the edit part of your answer, how do i set the x-requested with internally?

Comment: You cannot add headers with jQuery.load. I've added information on how to enable unobtrusive Ajax